# sqlite3_open - Can't open database?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have the following statement in my code:

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

but it doesn't seem to be opening my database.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What is the value of 'databasePath', and are you running the application on the iPhone-Simulator or a real device? Can you ensure that 'databasePath' points to an existing database or an empty path with a valid parent directory?

Comment: databasePath has the following details: /Users/stephenconnolly/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/C42A3304-8A6E-45B5-9618-5BD6A1B05335/Documents.

App is running on the simulator at the moment.

Comment: Your database path is an existing directory, add a filename to the path instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. If you want to reply to my question with a proper answer I'll mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing anything else about your problem, one can only assume that your path is invalid.

Try using this path to see if it works

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths lastObject];
NSString* databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydb.sqlite"];

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
     NSLog(@"Opened sqlite database at %@", databasePath);
    //...stuff
} else {
     NSLog(@"Failed to open database at %@ with error %s", databasePath, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
     sqlite3_close (database);
}
```

Comment: databasePath has the following details: /Users/stephenconnolly/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/C42A3304-8A6E-45B5-9618-5BD6A1B05335/Documents

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this filepath method

```
- (NSString *) filePath 
{    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```