# Retrieving database into an iphone app

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, offline

My iPhone app is required to work offline, so I need te retrieve the db from the server into the devise.
The database contains about 10 tables with a few dozen lines each.
What is the recommended way for doing so?
Is it the sqlite3?if so, how can I build the sqlite tables from the DB?

Thanks,
Asaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options:

- download a sqlite database file from webserver, store it in your app's document or temp folder
- create the database and tables dynamically by code, set up an XML or JSON interface on your webserver, download the data from web and insert to the new database

Take a look here for a [beginning with SQLite on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438089/using-sqlite-with-ios-very-beginner-program/10438440#10438440).

And yes, it is sqlite3 on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I ship my apps with the tables built, with some data, then have the app call a web service that takes "last updated" as a parameter, and returns all additions/deletions since then (as JSON)...the app then parses that, and inserts/updates/deletes as needed